# Migrating from Azure Sql to Azure Synapse, can't connect to Synapse in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, azure-synapse

So we are in the process of migrating from Azure SQL DB to Azure Synapse SQL Pools. I figured setting Airflow up to use the new database would be as simple as changing the server address and credentials, but when we try to connect to the database via Airflow it throws this error:

*40532, b'Cannot open server "1433" requested by the login.  The login failed.*

We use the generic mssqloperator and mssqlhook. I have verified the login info, pulled the server address directly from Synapse, and the synapse connection string shows port 1433 is correct, so I am at a loss for what could be causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The Airflow Connection schema we use is the Microsoft Sql Server Connection, with host being {workspace}.sql.azuresynapse.net, login being the admin login, password being the admin password, and port being 1433

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the port which was not enabled.

Make sure that port **1433** is open for outbound connections on all firewalls between the client and the internet.

Comment: That's the same port that our current connection to Azure SQL DB uses and it works just fine, plus wouldn't the port not come into play until reaching Azures services? it wouldn't be an outbound port from our airflow but an inbound port on Azure's side.